# Inequality of inclusion-exclusion terms

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, inclusion-exclusion

While analyzing the properties of an algorithm I am working on, I came up with the following inequality of inclusion-exclusion terms.

Let $0 \leq i \leq j < k$ be natural numbers. Then, I want to prove
$$
\sum_{a = 1}^{i} (-1)^{a+1} \frac{a}{k - a} \binom{k}{a} \binom{k - a}{k - i} \binom{k - a}{k - j} \geq 0
\ \text{.}
$$
The inequality seems fairly simple ($\frac{a}{k - a} > 0$). However, the alternating sign complicates things.
I have tried to develop a proof by induction but cannot identify the induction step.
Also, I have tried to partition the sum into positive and negative terms to handle them separately.

Example: If we look at $k=10$, $j=8$, and vary $i \in \lbrace 0, ..., 8 \rbrace$, we get the following summands:

```
k=10, i=0, j=8:  0 = []
k=10, i=1, j=8:  40 = [40]
k=10, i=2, j=8:  45 = [360, -315]
k=10, i=3, j=8:  0 = [1440, -2520, 1080]
k=10, i=4, j=8:  0 = [3360, -8820, 7560, -2100]
k=10, i=5, j=8:  0 = [5040, -17640, 22680, -12600, 2520]
k=10, i=6, j=8:  0 = [5040, -22050, 37800, -31500, 12600, -1890]
k=10, i=7, j=8:  0 = [3360, -17640, 37800, -42000, 25200, -7560, 840]
k=10, i=8, j=8:  0 = [1440, -8820, 22680, -31500, 25200, -11340, 2520, -180]
```

Note that no grouping of two, three, or four elements produces the desired sum.

**Edit:** By applying common identities from "Concrete Mathematics" (Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik), the problem statement is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{a=0}^{i-1} (-1)^a \frac{(k-a-2)!}{a! (i-a-1)! (j-a-1)!} \geq 0 \ \text{.}
$$

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first try, which might easily fail, would be to set $~j = 5, k = 10,~$ and do the actual numeric computation, 6 separate times, sseparately setting $~i~$ to each of the elements in $~\{0,1,2,\cdots, 5\}.~$  The point is that at first glance, I have no intuition developed on the problem. So, to attack the problem, I have no choice but to *apply elbow grease*.

Comment: Note that if the problem does happen to succumb to induction, it does not have to be induction on $~k.~$  The problem might succumb to induction on $~i,~$ or induction on $~j.$  Re previous comment, I am not referring to (for example) using a computer to output the raw computation(s).  Instead, I am referring to using scratch paper to manually express the computation(s), term by term, via exact fractions.

Comment: If it helps: $k = 10$, $j = 5$, $i = 0$: $0 \geq 0$; $i = 1$: $2541 \geq 2310$; $i = 2$: $19763 + 1/3 \geq 18480$; $i = 3$: $69877.5 \geq 66990$; $i = 4$: $148830 \geq 145530$; $i = 5$: $212597 \geq 210672$.

Comment: The point is not the results.  The point is what caused the results, which is why I emphasized examining the computations, term by term.  The idea is to develop your intuition to the point where you have (perhaps) a series of *insights*.  It is doubtful if examining the pertinent *final computations* will accomplish this.

Comment: For example, as you indicated, the $~(-1)^{a+1}~$ factor represents a *monkey wrench*.  So, it would seem that you have to examine the relative magnitude (i.e. absolute value) of each term, against all of the other terms, as $~a$ steps from $~1~$ through $~i.$

Comment: I've added more detail to the question. Yet, the answer has not revealed itself.

Comment: Personally, I have run out of ideas.  Assuming that this problem was assigned from a book/class, a *hail mary* pass might be to attempt to examine the theorems, worked examples, and previously solved problems that led up to this problem.  The presumption is that these prior results represent theory that you have been taught, and that the current problem is some sort of (arguably complicated) application of the theory.  That is, attempting to *get inside the head* of the problem composer **might** bear fruit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This is not a textbook problem, though. I'm a researcher, not a student.

Comment: It puts me in mind of the Bonferroni inequalities.

Comment: Seems interesting. The problem does not follow the inequalities described in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities), though. The partial sums do not follow this property.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459727/inequality-of-inclusion-exclusion-term

Comment: The question has been answered correctly on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/459727/inequality-of-inclusion-exclusion-term).